# Nodelet service failed on symbol lookup

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting a symbol mapping error on a nodelet I am trying to create/call.  Thank you for taking time to look at this issue. Please note this is my own nodelet not the same as the zed_ros_wrapper which is not a nodelet.

Note the additional "/" in the so path. See "lib//" in error msg after : system lookup error. Is this the issue?

```
[ INFO] [1454774540.899541309]: Loading nodelet /camera/zed_ros_wrapper_nodelet of type zed_ros_wrapper/ZedWrapperNodelet to manager standalone_nodelet with the following remappings:
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libzed_ros_wrapper_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZN15zed_ros_wrapper17ZedWrapperNodeletC1Ev
[FATAL] [1454774541.354151111]: Service call failed!
```

ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ nm -D /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libzed_ros_wrapper_nodelet.so  |  grep  _ZN15zed_ros_wrapper17ZedWrapperNodeletC1Ev

output from grep:

```
 U _ZN15zed_ros_wrapper17ZedWrapperNodeletC1Ev
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225986/nodelet-service-failed-on-symbol-lookup/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [nm documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html), the `U` at the beginning of the line means that symbol is undefined.

`_ZN15zed_ros_wrapper17ZedWrapperNodeletC1Ev`  is a mangled C++ name, so I put it through `c++filt` to get the actual function name for the undefined symbol: `zed_ros_wrapper::ZedWrapperNodelet::ZedWrapperNodelet()`

It looks like you haven't implemented the no-argument constructor for your nodelet.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3